# Что значит слово "болтать"?

Tags: этимология

В современном языке есть смыслы "болтать" - "много и бесполезно говорить" и "взбалтывать" - "перемешивать, встряхивать" и т.п. Какое из них первично?
Мне кажется, что исходным был смысл, связанный с физическим движением. Только не очень понятно, как он перешел на разговор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Болтать** - 1) двигать чем-либо из стороны в сторону; 2) разговаривать о неважном, незначительном (< болтать языком). В русском языке в 1-ом значении появилось раньше (XVII в.). Во 2-ом значении отмечается в словарях с 1731 года (*болтати, болтун*, там же - *болтунья*), *болтливый* - с 1780 года, *болтовня* (в знач. 'болтливый человек') - с 1789 года. Общеслав. форма возможно *bъltati, первоначально - о жидкости, о воде (ср.* бултых*,* булькать* и т.п.) (П.Я. Черных. Историко-этимологический словарь русского языка).
По-моему, понятно, почему исходный смысл, связанный с физическим движением, перешел на разговор: разговор - результат движения языка (или языком), и звукоподражание тоже очень кстати.